# Excel number of days spanned over 2 years

Tags: excel, date

I hope I can get some help with this problem I'm having.

I have to group data by a Sales person name then work out the number of days between 2 dates. I can do that no worries but if the person works over until the next year I have to calculate the number of days until the end of the year and then from the start of the next year until the end date.

Example:
Salesman Simon worked from 10/11/1994 until 16/01/1995

*|Simon|10/11/1994|16/01/1995|68 Days*

I need the spreadsheet to group by year so that the data is

*|Simon|*

*|10/1994|53 Days|*

Any ideas on how this might be done?
TIA

*|01/1995|15 Days|*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[image: If it's only]

You could use something like:

```
=IF(YEAR(C1)<>YEAR(B1),DATEDIF(B1,DATE(YEAR(B1),12,31),"d"))
```

and

```
=IF(YEAR(B1)<>YEAR(C1),DATEDIF(DATE(YEAR(C1),1,1),C1,"d"))
```

respectively.

Comment: Thanks heaps, just what I needed.